# How to fix error: variable out of scope in Haskell ghci

Tags: haskell, ghci

I use 'ghci' in Linux when I try:

```hs
    minuscula :: Char -> Bool
```

I get:

```
    Variable not in scope: minuscula :: Char -> Bool
    enter code here
```

Terminal Image:
[image: Terminal Img]

Comment: I'd recommend to write all your code in a .hs file, and then `:load` it from GHCi. GHCi is convenient to try evaluating some short expressions, but it is inconvenient to use when entering multi-line code -- using an editor is much simpler.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add the implementation of `minuscula`, you can write a set of line by wrapping these between `:{` and `:}`. If you let Haskell only interpret that single line, it sees a signature, but without a definition how the `minuscula` function is implemented. For example:

```
Prelude> :{
Prelude| minuscula :: Char -> Bool
Prelude| minuscula 'A' = True
Prelude| minuscula _ = False
Prelude| :}
```